# I can't update Visual Studio 2022 and can't download data storage and processing

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-installer

Data storage and processing are used for putting database by SQL in Windows form application but I think the main problem that makes it not download is the update of the Visual Studio I cannot update it because I get an error

This is what I download:

[image]

The network is very good I try by dataphone and wi-fi and get the same error:

[image]

Comment: Try downloading the latest version of the installer "Installer version 3.5.2150.18781" Here is the direct [MS link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&channel=Release&version=VS2022&source=VSLandingPage&cid=2030&workload=dotnet-dotnetwebcloud&passive=false#dotnet) Once downloaded right click and run as administrator.

Comment: Tried clicking the 'More troubleshooting tips' button and using the mentioned steps there?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is wrong with a network connection while downloading the update files. You may consider using the VS installer command line to download the update or the full installer locally and then run the installer from the cached folder on the disk, see [Use command-line parameters to install, update, and manage Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) for more information about such options.